# Maven import not working in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.4 Ultimate

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.4 Ultimate Edition on Windows installed using the EXE installer.
After installation when trying to import a Maven project, it does not work (no Maven dependencies appear in the project).

After installation when I try to import a Maven project, it does not work (no Maven dependencies appear in the project) and I can see the following message in the IDEA log:

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: The specified global settings file does not exist: `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.4\jbr\bin\conf\settings.xml`

The file really does not exist, but I have no idea why it is expected.

I was able to work around the issue by starting a command line as administrator and creating the mentioned file with an empty Maven configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <settings>
    </settings>
```

Comment: A similar problem was fixed in the 2023.2 IDE build - [IDEA-322338](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-322338). You can try using the latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion

Comment: To better understand what exactly caused a problem in your case please create a new issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and share the IDE logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data)